# KeyStroke for delete in Java Swing

Tags: java, macos, keyboard-events

I'm trying to use InputMap/ActionMap to intercept the delete key. I get it to work with Enter but it doesn't seem to respond with delete (this is on a Mac OSX so I wonder if that is part of the issue).

What am I doing wrong?

```
private void setupKeyBindings(final JList jlist) {
        String delAction = "deleteItems";
        KeyStroke delKey = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("DELETE");
        jlist.getInputMap().put(delKey, delAction);
        jlist.getActionMap().put(delAction, new AbstractAction()
        {
            @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("delete pressed");
                doDelete(jlist);
            }
        });     

        String enterAction = "useItems";
        KeyStroke enterKey = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ENTER");
        jlist.getInputMap().put(enterKey, enterAction);
        jlist.getActionMap().put(enterAction, new AbstractAction()
        {
            @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("enter pressed");
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `KeyStroke.getKeyStrokeForEvent(KeyEvent.VK_DELETE)`?  This is a shot in the dark, but how about `KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("BACKSPACE")`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hmm. The "delete" key on my Mac seems to map to KeyListener keycode 8 which I think is backspace. (There's just a delete key, not a separate backspace key, on my Mac keyboard, vs. Windows PC keyboards that have both)

The following appears to works for the Mac to map to Command-Delete:

```
KeyStroke delKey = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(
   KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE, InputEvent.META_MASK);
```

Comment: Correct; the Mac uses the term Delete for what on any other keyboard is Backspace.

Comment: To perform a true 'delete' the user needs to hold 'fn' and then press 'delete'. Just as an FYI.

Answer (score 3):

```
KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("BACK_SPACE");
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but this answered mine:

```
deleteAction.putValue(
    javax.swing.Action.ACCELERATOR_KEY,
    KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DELETE, 0)
);
```

You can find other KeyEvent integer constants here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html

Comment: thanks but that won't work on a Mac (at least not at the time of writing of the original question) since the delete key maps to the Java "backspace" concept.

Comment: @JasonS Yes, I am aware of that. But the accepted answer here didn't work for me on my windows machine, so I'm posting this answer here for windows users that come across this question.

Comment: this question has the `osx` tag.

Comment: @JasonS Yes, I am aware of that. But it was one of the first to come up in my google search, so I posted my answer here for other users that find this page first

Comment: ok, fair enough! you could post a question of your own and answer it.

Comment: @JasonS ok you got me there. I didn't think of that